# How to populate a report level variable from a dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to populate a report level variable from a dataset.

Background: I have a report that needs to perform a DB lookup to get a single row/column value. That value needs to populate a report level variable. Of data type datetime.

Here is something I have tried.
Click in report area
Under report properties I navigate to variables
Create a new variable and assign it a name.
Click on the "fx" button to open the dialog.
I use the "First" function in an attempt to assign the value.
I get the "...value expression for the report 'body' uses aggregate function First..." error.

Is there any way to make this happen at the report variable level?

Thanks,
Donnie

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a parameter? You can set the default value based on a query. If you don't want your users to overwrite it, make it hidden.